# Python requires string with ""?

Tags: python, string

```
test = input("What's your name")
print(test)
```

When I run this, it gives me an error if I type in, for example, `william`

```
  File "C:\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    test = input("What's your name")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'william' is not defined
```

The only thing that works is if I type it with quotes in the interpreter, but that's not how it's supposed to work. What's causing this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using Python 3.x instead?

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: You obviously aren't. You are using 2.x thus `input` evaluates the input. Use `raw_input`

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7, the `input` function will evaluate what it reads in.

Example:

```
>>> test = input("What is your name: ")
What is your name: 3 + 3
>>> print(test)
6
>>> type(test)
<type 'int'>
```

For python 2.7, you should use `raw_input` which will record whatever it reads in as a string.

Example:

```
>>> test = raw_input("What is your name: ")
What is your name: William
>>> print(test)
William
>>> type(test)
<type 'str'>
```